# Is $[a,b] \times \{c\}$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R^2}$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

Is $[a,b] \times \{c\}$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ ?

I believe this not to be the case. Take any "potential" homeomorphism $f : [a,b] \times \{c\} \to \mathbb{R^2}$. 
 Define $U \subset [a,c] \times \{c\}$ to be the set $([a,b] \times \{c\} \to \mathbb{R^2}) \ \not \ ((a,c) \cup (b,c) \cup (\frac{a+b}{2}, c)) $ .
U is disconnected, but $f(U) = \mathbb{R^2} \ \not \ (f(a,c) \cup f(b,c) \cup f(\frac{a+b}{2}))$ is connected, so $f$ can't be a homeomorphism.

Here is my issue: Although I believe my argument to hold it doesn't match with my intuition for why these two sets are not homeomorphic. A non- rigorous argument based on my intuition would be " $[a,b] \times \{c\}$ has "end points". However $ \mathbb{R^2}$ doesn't. They can't be homeomorphic".

Is there any way to make my intuition rigorous. Do my intuition and my argument even make sense/ hold true?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Isn't $[a,b] \times \{c\}$ homeo to $[a,b]$?  The $ \times \{c\}$ doesn't really add anything.

Comment: Sure... If that helps you can think of it as $[a,b]$.

Comment: Right, then it's clear by compactness.  Or, removing any point of the plane will not disconnect it, but that's not so for the interval.  So, done.

Comment: @ Randall Thank you!

Comment: First of all, $[a,b]\times\{c\}$ is homeomorphic to $[a,b].$ So you raelly want to know if $[a,b]$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2.$ That simplifies the problem.

Comment: Sure I went for the more complicated problem statement.Of course, [a,b] works also.

Comment: If you wish to *solve* a more complicated problem, and if you can reduce it to a *simpler* problem, then you've made progress towards the final solution. The only reason I can think of to make a simpler problem more complicated is to try to hide the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you remove a point (other than $(a,c)$ or $(b,c)$) from $[a,b]\times\{c\}$, it becomes disconnected. No point of $\mathbb R^2$ has that property.

You can also say that $[a,b]\times\{c\}$ is compact, whereas $\mathbb R^2$ isn't.

Comment: I see! I guess I intuited the compactness argument. "Has no endpoints" ---> unbounded ---> can't be compact?

Comment: Yes, a compact set in a metric space must be bounded.

Comment: Careful.  "Has no endpoints" does NOT mean unbounded. $(0,1)$ has no endpoints but it is certainly bounded.  You are applying the false converse.

Comment: "Has endpoints" is closer to being closed in a Euclidean space, not bounded.

Comment: Thank you. I see where I went wrong!